# How to get most recently date in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

There is a `guaccountid` with 3 different `guorderid` values and different `enddate`. I need to get only the latest `enddate`'s `guorderid` for the particular `guaccountid`.

```
select guaccountid,guorderid,enddate
from ord_entitlement
where guaccountid ='15031021282118408'
ORDER BY enddate DESC
```

[image: see the out put for my query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `row_number()` window function:

```
SELECT   
  guaccountid, 
  guorderid,
  enddate
FROM (
  SELECT
    guaccountid, 
    guorderid,
    enddate, 
    row_number() over (
      partition by guaccountid 
      order by to_timestamp(enddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') desc
    ) r
  FROM ord_entitlement
  WHERE guaccountid = '15031021282118408'
    AND substr(enddate, 1, 4) != '9999'
  ) src
WHERE r = 1;
```

This would return:

```
|       guaccountid |         guorderid |            enddate |
|-------------------|-------------------|--------------------|
| 15031021282118408 | 15031708485830901 | 2015-04-16T08:42:1 |
```

If you remove `guaccountid = '15031021282118408'` from the `where` clause you would get the latest record for any `guaccountid`.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1c5ef/7)

Comment: Isn't a window function in a sub-query a little over the top here? You are potentially doing **a lot** of work in the sub-query that is of no consequence to the output.

Comment: @Patrick Sure, it does a little bit more work - I wouldn't say a lot though, certainly not if the accountid is constrained - but in the end it gives the correct result with only the row with the most recent date and nothing else. I guess getting the desired data should be worth the extra processing.